# ionic 3 access object in view file

Tags: ionic-framework

this will set the data in the Storage in signup.ts

```
this.storage.set('signUser',body);
```

the below will retrieve the data from storage in home.ts

```
public userDetails: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
this.storage.get('signUser').then((data) => {
  this.userDetails = data;
  console.log(data);
});
}
```

and the JSON response, in console.log(data);

```
addresses:[]
disable_auto_group_change:0
email:"ader@test.com"
extension_attributes:{is_subscribed: false}
firstname:"adf"
group_id:1
id:20442
lastname:"adf"
store_id:1
updated_at:"2018-05-30 08:40:02"
website_id:1
```

i can print the JSON in the console, how access the object in view file ?

I tried it accessing in home.html

```
{{userDetails.firstname}}
```

got an error saying cannot read property of 'firstname' of undefined

How to access it in the view file ?

Comment: In your object i am not seeing firstname key

Comment: i have updated my json response.

Comment: Can you please use JSON.parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that `userDetails` is still `undefined` at the moment the view is first rendered.

There are indeed various solutions:

You could simply assign a default value in your component so it wouldn't be undefined.

```
public userDetails: any = {firstname:''};
```

More simply, you can use the *elvis* operator `?.` (if available).

```
{{userDetails?.firstname}}
```

It could be wiser to use use an `ngIf` so you could hide a whole section displaying userDetails values.

```
<div *ngIf="userDetails">....{{userDetails?.firstname}}...</div>
```

You could use [`async` pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) to handle values set after asynchronous calls (it subscribes to Observable or Premise).

```
{{yourObservableOrPromise | async}}
```

See more info [here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else)

Comment: Runtime Errro : InvalidPipeArgument: 'adf' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: my fault : the async pipe requires an `Observable` or a `Promise`as argument